# What is "Your Presence" API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sensors, user-presence

I was accessing a sites permissions and noticed "Your Presence"

[image: Picture]

So, what does this mean? Is there an API for this? Does this bring up the sensor prompt?

If this is an API, I would like to know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google leads me to [this page](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=878979), which says:

> idle-detection: Change "User presence" to "Your presence"

and

> Summary:

> There's a chrome.idle.* API that allows chrome apps to detect when the user is active or idle, and when the screen is locked. We should expose something similar to the web for use by chat apps, etc.

See [Sensor APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs) on MDN, [Proximity Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Proximity_Events), and the [Idle Detection API](https://web.dev/idle-detection/).

> The Idle Detection API notifies developers when a user is idle, indicating such things as lack of interaction with the keyboard, mouse, screen, activation of a screensaver, locking of the screen, or moving to a different screen. A developer-defined threshold triggers the notification.

It's very experimental technology that's still in development. It looks like it hasn't fully launched yet.